# Two full RecyclerViews in A ScrollView, only scroll in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nested, scrollview

I want to show two different lists inside a ScrollView.
I can't show two full lists with all their items.

What I don't need:
Divide my screen in two parts that hold a scrollable list.

What I need:
One scrollview with two recyclerviews that show all their items.

What I have now:

```
<!-- ScrollView for the lists -->
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: if you wanna show full recyclerView why nnot take listview ??

Comment: have you check `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` ?

Answer (score 2):

Make a single recyclerview and with a good adapter implementation you can achieve what you want. (Multiple viewtypes in a single adapter)

Using a NestedScrollView and two recyclerviews with nested scrolling enabled will render all the items in the adapters, so there is no view recyclering and depends how long your lists are, how complex your views will be, you will run out of memory pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You should definetly have a look at the NestedScrollView

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as
>   both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions
>   of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Comment: This partially fixed it for me! I did needed to add this line to make scrolling work smooth: ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(myRecyclerView, false);